# draw a google line chart with three axial

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

i try to get image of a three axial google chart but don't display any line chart , like below :

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=x,y,r&chxr=1,734238,882088|2,993,1431&cht=lc&chd=t:850751,852364,828412,801830,772874,734238,768322,804502,844117,882088,839063,832920|&1364,1431,1380,1263,1168,1093,993,1099,1285,1261,1330,1261,1175&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0&chs=200x125
```

we have three axial and different range numbers and want to show this two data series in one google line chart image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with something like below you can draw two different range series :

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:2768,2538,2439,1205,1367,1694,1897,2011|2722,2686,2669,2669,2669,2667,2666,2666&chxt=x,y,r&chs=450x200&chds=1205,2768,2666,2722&chxr=2,2666,2722|1,1205,2768|0,1,8,1&chg=3,50,1,0,3&chco=0a6cff,ff9e0c&chdl=visit|price&chdlp=r
```